# How to cancel this Jacobi amplitude, elliptic integral, and incomplete beta function composition?

Tags: special-functions, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition, elliptic-integrals, beta-function

**Problem and Context:**

$\def\K{\operatorname K}\def\F{\operatorname F} \def\sn{\operatorname{sn}} \def\B{\operatorname B} \def\I{\operatorname I} \def\E{\operatorname E}\def\am{\operatorname{am}}$
An inverse of [elliptic E$(z,m)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html), [elliptic F$(z,m)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticF.html), and the [incomplete beta B$_x(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28x%2Ca%2Cb%29) function uses the [Jacobi amplitude am$(z,m)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiAmplitude.html) and [inverse beta regularized I$^{-1}_x(a,b)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseBetaRegularized/):

$$\E(z,\sqrt[-3]{-1})-\left(\frac12+\frac i{2\sqrt3}\right)\F(z,\sqrt[-3]{-1})=a\implies z=\am\left(\frac{\sqrt[12]{-1}}{2\cdot3^\frac34}\B_{\I^{-1}_{1-\sqrt[4]3\sqrt[3]4\sqrt[12]{-1}\B z}\left(\frac23,\frac 12\right)}\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)+\frac{\sqrt[12]{-1}(2\sqrt3+3i)}{2^\frac433^\frac34\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right),\sqrt[-3]{-1}\right)\tag1$$

with the [Baxter constant B](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=baxter+constant) [shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+EllipticE%28x%2C%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29%29-%281%2F2%2Bi%2F%282%E2%88%9A3%29%29EllipticF%28x%2C%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29%29%3D+-%28-1%29%5E%2811%2F12%29%2F%282+2%5E%282%2F3%29+3%5E%281%2F4%29%29) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=am%28%28-1%29%5E%281%2F12%29%2F%282+3%5E%283%2F4%29%29+beta%28inversebetaregularized%281-baxter%2F2%2C2%2F3%2C+1%2F2%29%2C1%2F3%2C+1%2F2%29+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F12%29+%28%283+i+%2B+2+sqrt%283%29%29+%CE%93%281%2F3%29%5E3%29%2F%284+2%5E%281%2F3%29+3%5E%283%2F4%29+%CF%80%29%2C%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29%29). An identity is:

$$\am\left(\frac{\sqrt[12]{-1}}{2\cdot3^\frac34}\B_y\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)+\frac{\sqrt[12]{-1}(2\sqrt3+3i)}{2^\frac433^\frac34\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right),\sqrt[-3]{-1}\right)=\am\left(\sqrt[3]{-1}\F(w,\sqrt[-3]{-1})-\frac{\sqrt{11\sqrt3i-15}}{2^\frac{17}6\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right),\sqrt[-3]{-1}\right),w=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt3\sqrt[6]{-1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt3\sqrt[3]{-iy}+\sqrt[3]{-1}+1}}\right)\tag2$$
and
$$\text{sn}\left(\frac{(-1)^\frac34}{2\cdot 3^\frac34}\B_\frac{\left(\frac3{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{-1}-1\right)^3i}{3\sqrt3}\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)+\frac{\sqrt[12]{-1}}{2^\frac43\sqrt[4]3\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right),\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)=\sqrt[6]{-1}x\tag3$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+JacobiSN%28+%28-1%29%5E%283%2F4%29%2F%282+3%5E%283%2F4%29%29+beta%28%28i+%283%2Fx%5E2-%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+-1%29%5E3%29%2F%283+sqrt%283%29%29%2C+1%2F3%2C+1%2F2%29+%2B%28%28-1%29%5E%281%2F12%29+%CE%93%281%2F3%29%5E3%29%2F%282%5E%284%2F3%29+3%5E%281%2F4%29+%CF%80%29%2C%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29%29%2C%28-1%29%5E%281%2F6%29+x) as a concept proof with [Jacobi sn$(z,m)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiSN/). $(1)$ almost displays [$\am(x,m)$ periodicity](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiAmplitude/04/02/03/) with [Elliptic K$(m)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticK.html):

$$\K\left(\sqrt[-3]{-1}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[4]3\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right)}{2^\frac73\sqrt[12]{-1}\pi}, \K\left(\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[4]3 \sqrt[12]{-1}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right)}{2^\frac73\pi} $$

**Strategy:**

Likely the [sn$(u+v,m)$ formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiSN/16/02/0001/), since $\sn\left(\frac{\sqrt[12]{-1}(2\sqrt3+3i)}{2^\frac433^\frac34\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right),\sqrt[-3]{-1}\right)$ etc has a closed form, [Jacobi transformations](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiAmplitude/16/01/01/), and finally $\am(\F(x,m),m)=x$ will simplify $(1)$. However, I am not that experienced with elliptic functions, so help is wanted.

$(1)$ is likely expressible in terms of I$^{-1}_x\left(\frac23,\frac12\right)$ only without other special functions. What is a simplification for $(2)$, like in $(3)$?

Comment: [This](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiAmplitude/16/01/01/) identity may help

Comment: Hello Tyma can you help me on a bountied question I post recently (Special sum ...$S<e$)   +1 for the problem.

Comment: @ErikSatie Sure; I will look into it. Do you think you can help with this question too?

Comment: Very Very naive question have you tried a polynomial trick?

Comment: Or a discriminant ?

Comment: With Lagrange inversion theorem (hum perhaps it's nothing but speak is half an answer.;-)

Comment: @ErikSatie Elliptic function theory, which is new to both of us, works better than Lagrange inversion since $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}f^n(x)$ with $f(x)$ a special function is hard to calculate without a general formula

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1981-36-154/S0025-5718-1981-0606513-8/ hope it helps.

Comment: Correction for all: It is $1-\sqrt[4]3\sqrt[3]4\sqrt[12]{-1}\text B a$ for $(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\sn{\operatorname{sn}}\def\cn{\operatorname{cn}}\def\am{\operatorname{am}}\def\dn{\operatorname{dn}}\def\m{\sqrt[-3]{-1}}\def\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}$ Using [inverse Jacobi sn$^{-1}(x,m)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseJacobiSN.html): $$z=-\am(\sqrt[3]{-1}\text F(\sin^{-1}(u),\m)+c,\m)\iff-\sin(z)=\sn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u,\m)+c,\m),c=-\frac{\sqrt{11\sqrt3i-15}}{2^\frac{17}6\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right)$$ Use the [sn$(u+v,m)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiSN/16/02/0001/) formula with [Jacobi cn$(x,m)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiCN.html) and [Jacobi dn$(x,m)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiDN.html). A problem is that am$\left(\frac{\sqrt{11\sqrt3i-15}}{2^\frac{17}6\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right),\m\right)=(a+b i)\infty;a,b>0$ with unknown $a,b$, so there is a limit. Each Jacobi function has the same $m$ omitted: $$\sn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u,\m)+c,\m)=\\\lim_{c\to-\frac{\sqrt{11\sqrt3i-15}}{2^\frac{17}6\pi}\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right)}\frac{\cn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u))\dn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u))\sn(c)+\cn(c)\dn(c)\sn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u))}{1-\m(\sn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u))\sn(c))^2}$$ with [Jacobi transformations](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiAmplitude/16/01/01/): $$\sn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u,\m),\m)=\sqrt[3]{-1}\sgn(u)\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{(-1)^\frac23u^2+1}}$$ $$\cn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u,\m),\m)=\frac1{\sqrt{(-1)^\frac23u^2+1}}$$ $$\dn(\sqrt[3]{-1}\sn^{-1}(u,\m),\m)=\sqrt{\frac{1-u^2}{(-1)^\frac23u^2+1}}$$

Let’s mimic the divergence of the Jacobi functions at $x=c$:

$$\lim_{c\to\infty}\frac{a(1+i)c+b ((1-i)c)^2}{1- p((1-i)c)^2}=-\frac bp,b=\sqrt p= \sqrt[3]{-1}\sgn(u)\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{(-1)^\frac23u^2+1}}\implies-\sin(z)=-\frac1{ \sqrt[3]{-1}\sgn(u)\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{(-1)^\frac23u^2+1}}}$$

Therefore simplify into:

$$\boxed{\operatorname E(z,\sqrt[-3]{-1})-\left(\frac12+\frac i{2\sqrt3}\right)\operatorname F(z,\sqrt[-3]{-1}) =a\implies z=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[12]{-1}}{\sqrt[4]3}\sqrt{1-\sqrt[3]{\operatorname I^{-1}_{1-\sqrt[4]3\sqrt[3]4\sqrt[12]{-1}\text Ba}\left(\frac23,\frac12\right)}}\right),0\le \sqrt[12]{-1}a\le \frac1{\sqrt[4]3\sqrt[3]4\text B}}$$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=EllipticE%28x%2C%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29%29-%281%2F2%2Bi%2F%282%E2%88%9A3%29%29EllipticF%28x%2C%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29%29%2B%28-1%29%5E%2811%2F12%29%2F%282+2%5E%282%2F3%29+3%5E%281%2F4%29%29%2Cx%3D+asin%28sqrt%28%28-1%29%5E%281%2F6%29%2F3%5E%281%2F2%29%281+-+%28inversebetaregularized%281-baxter%2F2.0%2C2%2F3%2C1%2F2%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%29%29) with the [Baxter constant B](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Baxter+constant)